# Как использовать способность gcc генерировать правила для makefile внутри самого makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

У меня есть проект, в котором заголовочные файлы хранятся в папке `include`, а файлы реализации в папке `src`, объектные файлы я планирую собирать в папку `obj`. С помощью команды

```
gcc -MM -Iinclude src/somefile1.c src/somefile2.c
```

я получаю набор правил вида

```
somefile1.o: src/somefile1.c include/someheader.h
somefile2.o: src/somefile2.c include/someheader.h
```

выводимых в консоль

Список файлов в `src` тоже можно получить в пределах makefile вот так:

```
$(wildcard src/*.c)
```

Я пытаюсь создать шаблонное правило, которое бы обошло всё, что возвращает `$(wildcard src/*.c)`, и для каждого файла сгенерировало бы подходящее правило, так чтобы ещё и объектные файлы писались в папку obj, но у меня ничего не получается. Может, как-то можно заставить gcc выдавать только список заголовочных файлов? Тогда можно было бы написать что-то такое:

```
$(OBJS): obj/%.o: src/%.cpp $(shell gcc -getheaders src/%.cpp)
```

(понятное дело, что никакой опции -getheaders у GCC нет). Подразумевается, что `OBJS` - это список всех объектных файлов с папкой `obj`

Или, может, как-нибудь обработать то, что вернёт команда, чтобы выкинуть оттуда лишнее? Или надо как-то сделать, чтобы один Makefile сгенерировал другой, а потом запустил?

**UPD:**

Оказывается, работает вариант, когда есть шаблонное правило с командами + нешаблонное без команд:

```
obj\multithreading.o obj\main.o : include\test_functions.h
$(OBJS): obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -c -Iinclude $<
```

Но такие нешаблонные правила, которые влияют только на зависимости тоже можно было бы генерировать по тому, что файл .h встречается в директивах `#include`, но я всё равно не знаю, как это делать. В принципе, результат уже неплохой, но мне кажется, что это ещё как-то можно сделать более автоматически.

**UPD 2**:

Мне уже удалось создать переменную, значение которой соответствует таким дополнительным правилам, которые требуется добавить.

```
define NEWLINE


endef

DEPEN:=$(shell g++ -MM -Iinclude $(SOURCES))
DEPEN:=$(filter %.o: include/%.h,$(DEPEN))
DEPEN:=$(patsubst %.o:,$(NEWLINE)obj/%.o:, $(DEPEN))
```

Но когда я просто помещаю `$(DEPEN)`, я получаю ошибку "несколько образцов цели.  Останов.". Если помещаю `$(wildcard DEPEN)`, то оно не ругается, но и зависимости не появляются. Я как-то не понял, почему по отдельности дополнительные правила к шаблону работают, а если их сгенерировать автоматом, то нет?

Comment: Обычно для таких целей используют [makedepend](https://linux.die.net/man/1/makedepend). Почитайте

Comment: А что это вообще такое? Это команда Linux или функция в make?

Comment: Команда. man 1 он всегда про команды

Comment: А чем это отличается от `gcc -MM somefile.c > makefile`? Я бы даже сказал, что обращаться за этим делом к компилятору даже надёжнее.

Comment: Вы man-то прочли? Возможно лишь тем, что редактирует существующий makefile после строки `# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.`, возможно (как пишут авторы), что работает на порядок быстрее. Остальное (префиксы-суффиксы) вроде бы тоже есть в ключах gcc (но внимательно не сравнивал)

Comment: Прочёл и поигрался с ним. Это не то, что мне было нужно. А вот функция `eval` (см. мой ответ на свой вопрос) позволила сделать то, что я хотел.

Comment: Не относится к собственно вопросу, но я бы посоветовал не усложнять мэйкфайлы, а делать их по возможности проще. Иначе через некоторое время обязательно возникнут проблемы, если потребуется модифицировать такой файл (особенно актуально при модификации чужих мэйков). Отлаживать замучаетесь. Т.е. сейчас (в процессе активного изучения) вы "в теме" и хорошо все помните. Через год половину уже позабудете, поскольку не пишете же вы эти файлы каждый день?

Comment: Ну, покамест у меня есть ощущение, что универсальный мэйкфайл писался и отлаживался один раз, а после этого уже несколько раз использовался повторно. Единственное, что туда добавился модуль для автоматических тестов, но в целом он действительно покрывает большинство задач.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пара дней упорных поисков - и оно заработало. Оказывается, чтобы превратить переменную в набор правил, требуется написать:

```
$(eval $(DEPEN))
```

Получившийся Makefile позволяет собрать программу, состоящую из произвольных файлов `.cpp` и `.h`, разложенных в папки `src` и `include` соответственно, корректно учитывая все директивы `#include` для определения зависимостей, в том числе и транзитивных (когда один заголовочный файл включён в другой). Явно указывать эти файлы в Makefile не требуется, он всё найдёт и обработает сам.

**Итоговый результат (вдруг кому ещё такое понадобится)**

**Linux:**

```
# Имя исполняемого файла, который должен получиться
EXEC:=cpp-features

# Папки, в которых находятся файлы *.cpp и .h
SRC:=src
HDR:=include

# Папки, в которых окажутся артефакты компиляции
ifndef BUILD
BIN:=bin
else
BIN:=bin/$(BUILD)
endif
OBJ:=obj

# Ищем все файлы исходного кода    
SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
# Генерируем по именам файлов исходного кода имена объектных файлов */
OBJS:=$(SOURCES:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)

# Переменная со значением "перевод строки" - нужна для генерации правил
define NEWLINE


endef

# Спрашиваем у компилятора список зависимостей по #include    
DEPEN:=$(shell g++ -MM -I$(HDR) $(SOURCES))
# Оставляем только объектные и заголовочные файлы
DEPEN:=$(filter %.o: $(HDR)/%.h,$(DEPEN))
# Восстанавливаем переводы строк, добавляем путь к объектым файлам
DEPEN:=$(patsubst %.o:,$(NEWLINE)$(OBJ)/%.o:, $(DEPEN))

.PHONY: all clean

# В релизной сборке объектные файлы не нужны
ifeq ($(BUILD), Release)
.INTERMEDIATE:  $(OBJS)
endif

all: $(BIN)/$(EXEC)

# Вставляем в текущий файл правила, сгенерированные компилятором    
$(eval $(DEPEN))

# Шаблонное правило для сборки всех объектных файлов    
$(OBJS): $(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp | $(OBJ)
    @echo "Compiling file $<..."
    -g++ -o $@ -c -I$(HDR) $<

# Линковка    
$(BIN)/$(EXEC): $(OBJS) | $(BIN)
    @echo "Linking..."
    g++ -o $@ -pthread $(OBJS)
    @echo "Build succeeded!"

$(BIN) $(OBJ):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BIN)
    -rm -rf $(OBJ)
```

**Windows:**

```
# Принципиально тут всё так же, как для Linux, просто есть
# нюансы с форматами путей, поэтому комментарии см. выше
EXEC=cpp-features.exe
BIN=bin\Win
OBJ=obj\Win

HDR=include
SRC=src

SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
# этот комментарий просто чтобы адекватно отображалось на сайте */
SOURCES:=$(SOURCES:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(SRC)\\%.cpp)
OBJS:=$(SOURCES:$(SRC)\\%.cpp=$(OBJ)\\%.o)

define NEWLINE


endef

DEPEN:=$(shell g++ -MM -I$(HDR) $(SOURCES))
DEPEN:=$(filter %.o: $(HDR)/%.h,$(DEPEN))
DEPEN:=$(subst /,\,$(DEPEN))
DEPEN:=$(patsubst %.o:,$(NEWLINE)$(OBJ)\\%.o:, $(DEPEN))

.PHONY: all clean

ifeq ($(BUILD), Release)
.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJS)
endif

all: $(BIN)\$(EXEC)

$(eval $(DEPEN))

$(OBJS): $(OBJ)\\%.o: $(SRC)\\%.cpp | $(OBJ)
    @echo Compiling file $<...
    g++ -o $@ -c -I$(HDR) $<

$(BIN)\$(EXEC): $(OBJS) | $(BIN)
    @echo Linking...
    g++ -o $@ $(OBJS)
    @echo Build succeeded!

$(BIN) $(OBJ):
    mkdir $@

clean:
    -rd $(BIN) /S /Q
    -rd $(OBJ) /S /Q
```